# How to discover which script is controlling an element?

Tags: javascript, html, web

Here's my case :

I'm a beginner. I visited a website today on Chrome. There was a progress bar (actually, a `<div>`) in it. I wanted to make the progress bar go slower. So, I inspected the element. It's doesn't have an id but some script is controlling. I went through many scripts in that page but didn't find the one I want to edit.

Is there any way by which I can know the script controlling the element and edit it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

F12 Developer Tools select the element.